# Running native image of javafx app fails cause of java.lang.ClassNotFoundException -> "Solid_TextureRGB_AlphaTest_Loader"

Tags: java, maven, javafx, gluon, graalvm

I tried to run the native image of my javafx app on windows 10.
The app starts without any widget. I only have the following log:

> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:52 MEZ 2021][INFO] ==================== RUN TASK ====================
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:52 MEZ 2021][FINE] PB Command for run until end: c:\Users\...\target\client\x86_64-windows\MyApp.exe
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:52 MEZ 2021][FINE] Start process run until end...
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB] **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.prism.shader.Solid_TextureRGB_AlphaTest_Loader**
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.hub.ClassForNameSupport.forName(ClassForNameSupport.java:60)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.lang.Class.forName(DynamicHub.java:1247)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DResourceFactory.createStockShader(D3DResourceFactory.java:411)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderContext.getSpecialShader(BaseShaderContext.java:318)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderContext.validateTextureOp(BaseShaderContext.java:579)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderContext.validateTextureOp(BaseShaderContext.java:507)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.prism.impl.BaseGraphics.drawTexture(BaseGraphics.java:432)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.prism.impl.ps.BaseShaderGraphics.drawTexture(BaseShaderGraphics.java:139)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.paintTiles(NGRegion.java:2007)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderBackgroundRectangle(NGRegion.java:971)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderAsRectangle(NGRegion.java:754)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:575)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.thread.JavaThreads.threadStartRoutine(JavaThreads.java:519)
> [So. Jan. 31 17:10:53 MEZ 2021][INFO] [SUB]     at com.oracle.svm.core.windows.WindowsJavaThreads.osThreadStartRoutine(WindowsJavaThreads.java:138)

Can someone tell me what to do?

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <javafx.version>15.0.1</javafx.version>
    <attach.version>4.0.10</attach.version>
    <client.plugin.version>0.1.36</client.plugin.version>
    <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.5</javafx.plugin.version>
    <mainClassName>MyApp</mainClassName>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>${javafx.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
        <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>display</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
        <artifactId>util</artifactId>
        <version>${attach.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>Gluon</id>
        <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${client.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <target>${client.target}</target>
                <enableSWRendering>true</enableSWRendering>
                <attachList>
                    <list>display</list>
                    <list>lifecycle</list>
                    <list>statusbar</list>
                    <list>storage</list>
                </attachList>
                <resourcesList>
                    <list>.*\\.txt</list>
                </resourcesList>
                <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>desktop</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <client.target>host</client.target>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                <artifactId>display</artifactId>
                <version>${attach.version}</version>
                <classifier>desktop</classifier>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
                <version>${attach.version}</version>
                <classifier>desktop</classifier>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
                <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
                <version>${attach.version}</version>
                <classifier>desktop</classifier>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>ios</id>
        <properties>
            <client.target>ios</client.target>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>android</id>
        <properties>
            <client.target>android</client.target>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Usually that means that the missing class is used via reflection, so it has to be included in a reflectionList or GraalVM won't find it. Most of the shader classes are included already (you can see that in the `target/client/x86_64-windows/gvm/reflectionconfig-x86_64-windows.json` file, but not this one. So you just need to include it in the `<reflectionList/>` configuration. See also https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_reflectionlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You again José Pereda. I added the class `com.sun.prism.shader.Solid_TextureRGB_AlphaTest_Loader` to the `<reflectionList/>` in my pom.xml and it works.